# Incorrect directory separator on Windows with WordPress

Tags: php, windows, wordpress, directory, separator

This error occurs with WordPress while uploading.  My hosting OS is Windows.

It gives an error close to this:

```
Could not upload the  file ... \a\b\c\wp-content/uploads/2011/01
```

Do you know what the problem is?  How can I change the directory separator in WordPress?  (If this is the solution?)

Comment: PHP will translate between unix-style `/` and windows-style `\\` without trouble. It looks a bit weird in error message, but it's fine for PHP. check if your webserver's userID has write permissions on that particular folder.

Comment: thanks mark,i did not know that php dose not have problem with "\" and "/" on directory pathing,i changed permission upload folder and problem solved :).

Comment: php does not translate them, on linux both `\\` and `/` are fine, so you should always build your applications using `\` to get cross compatibility out the way.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can do define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); and then where ever a link is concatenated you need to have the DS in the middle so that it will work on both Windows and Linux servers.